# How can I sell caller's tokens via contract function and send them to the caller?

Tags: solidity

I have a function to claim an accumulated token amount like below. But its throwing TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED. What is the safest way to do this?

```
function claimAccumulatedAmount() public {
    _swapForBNB(_msgSender(), _msgSender(), getAccumulatedAmount(_msgSender()));
}

function _swapForBNB(address spender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
    _approve(spender, address(swapRouter), amount);
    swapRouter.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        amount,
        0, // slippage is unavoidable
        sellPath,
        recipient,
        block.timestamp
    );
}
```

Comment: Without looking at the rest of the contract is hard to say where the tokens are deposited. My guess is that spender should be `address(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution;
Transfer tokens to address(this) and approve router then make the swap.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same one I met with a week ago. Are you using ERC721 as base contract?? If you are using them , it's not working by aproving your contract address as approved address. It will also throw error like, "The approved address has no balnce" (not the exact error kind of like this). I tried by commenting the require method and it worked!!